# row_number over partition performance from PowerBi

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I have a a view which has a query in SQL Server 2019 using row_number over partition in a left join:

```
from
tableA
left join
(
(row_number over partition query)
) b on a.field=tableA.field
```

this query resulted in SSMS in 9 sec. execution time (used as a view)
If this view is used in another view, the query finish also fine in SSMS but times out in PowerBi.

I have a colleague of mine who is claiming the issue is due to usage of (row_number over partition query) that it is not good for PowerBi but I dont get it how this will matter when the view is SQL server , how this can have an impact on PowerBi?
**Verified that after changing the view with a table instead, its working fine in PowerBi.

Type of query from PowerBi: "Import"

Thanks.

Comment: In PowerBI is it Import or DirectQuery?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with ROW_NUMBER. The problem with PQ is the way it fetches the data from SQL. The general perception is PQ should execute the query at the same time as SSMS and that is not the case. PQ executes that query at least twice, once to check the type and secondly to get the data. There is an inherent fault within PQ and there has been a lot of discussion regarding this in the POWER BI forum.

Comment: One of the ways I got around this problem was by creating a SQL table variable and inserting the result in the table variable which did speed up PQ's execution.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft , I will survey this and return back. Thanks!

Comment: @smpa01 , Very interesting, I will read more on that, Thank you!
This workaround with table variable, I just check it and seems like a virtual table instead of what I did, real table , I just don't understand as far as I read , the virtual table disappears after end of code so this cannot do the job to store data all time and be fetched from powerBi, isn't that correct?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, its Import